# Render XML with embeded PDF using XSLT

Tags: xml, xslt, pdf, xslt-2.0

I have an XML document that has an encoded non-XML PDF contained with in it.

```
  <component>
<nonXMLBody>
  <text mediaType="application/pdf" representation="B64">JVBERi0xLjQKJeLjz9MKNyAwIG9iago8PC9UeXBlL1hPYmplY3QvQ29sb3JTcGFjZS9EZXZpY2VS.......
```

Is there a way I can extract that PDF and render it using XSLT?

Comment: `xls` meaning Microsoft Excel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, you can extract it (`<xsl:result-document href="zzz"><xsl:value-of select="text"/>` but you can't decode it (unless your system has a non standard extension function to do that). So you'd have to decode as a separate step using a different tool.

By default the XDM data model string type doesn't allow control characters not allowed in XML data, so there isn't a standard XPath type that can hold a binary blob produced by decoding the base64 encoded string. Extension functions can return objects of implementation-specific types, so they can do anything....